# Handling an identified Module in C

Tags: c, node.js, add-on

I have written a test addon (a non-instancing little hello world app) for Node.JS, and I am now playing around with plugin-able addons. I am currently trying to create a addon that can access the hello world addon's functions, as well as the hello world calling the plugin host addon with a registration of presence.

As of yet, the only way I can determine so far is for a .js file to require both addons, then  a call to the Hello World addon for the registration, then the plugin-host call. So, in short the coding would look like:

```
var host = require('./pluginHost');
host.registerPlugin(require('./helloWorldPlugin').plugin());
host.registerPlugin(require('./fooBarBazPlugin').plugin());
host.registrationComplete();
```

In actuality, there might be a bit more configuration code, but this is more of a concept at the moment. So, given the code above, withing the `pluginHost` addon code, how could I access & download information from that object. Bare in mind, the plugin part of the code that is being parsed to the `pluginHost` would be a static collection of functions that would contain information about the other objects and classes available as well as a mainline IPC between the `pluginHost` and other `plugins`.

Answer (score 0):

Righto, discovered how to do it

C++:

```
Handle<Value> registerPlugin(const Arguments &args) {
    HandleScope scope;
    Handle<Object> This = args.This();
    Handle<Context> context = Context::New();
    Handle<Object> object = This->Get(String::New("ObjectValueIWantKey"))->ToObject();

    if (object == Undefined()) {
        return Undefined();
    }

    Handle<Value> functionName = object->Get(String::New("SomeFunctionName"));
    if (functionName->IsFunction()) {
        Handle<Function> function = Handle<Function>::Cast(functionName);
        Handle<Value> fargs[1] = { String::New("ARG") };
        Handle<Value> methodResult = function->Call(object, 1, fargs);
    }

    Handle<Value> variableResult = object->Get(String::New("SomePropertyName"));

    ...
}
```

With this example, by calling `host.registerPlugin(require('./pluginObject'))` will allow the `pluginHost` library to interface with it, and include it for other systems.