# Calling Require with a C++ Addon

Tags: c++, node.js, requirejs, add-on

When programming a C++ Node.JS Addon, what is the equivalent of `require('./someModule')` so that a Module can be loaded for use within a compiled Addon?

I have found this method:

```
Handle<String> source = 
    String::New("NameOfLibrary.register(require('./someModule'))");
Handle<Script> script = 
    Script::Compile(source);
script->Run();
```

which if used in conjunction with [what I asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17438824/handling-an-identified-module-in-c) would work nicely, but I was wondering if there was a more native way.

Comment: You mean `C++` I assume?

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yes, sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to access the standard module require function in your initialization function. Generally I'd just call it from there since lazy calls to `require` aren't  a good idea since they are synchronous.

```
static void init (Handle<Object> target, Handle<Object> module) {
    HandleScope scope;
    Local<Function> require = Local<Function>::Cast(
        module->Get(String::NewSymbol("require")));

    Local<Value> args[] = {
        String::New("./someModule")
    };
    Local<Value> someModule = require->Call(module, 1, args);

    // Do whatever with the module
}


NODE_MODULE(module_file_name, init);
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this using Napi? In `Init(Napi::Env env, Napi::Object exports)`